# Mongo Format for Storing dates (or response format)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Does Mongo store underlying dates in different formats depending on the Date? I've got 2 Date fields that in Robo3T come back as a Date object. However, when running an aggregation query where I had to write a BsonDateAdapter to handle the Document, I can see one has been stored as a $numberLong.

```
"dateOne": {
    "$date": "2021-09-01T04:00:00Z"
},
"dateTwo": {
    "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "-86400000"
    }
},
```

dateTwo evaluates to 1969-12-31 00:00:00.000Z so I was wondering if it's before 1970 it does that? Or is it because someone manually updated this date incorrectly? And actually I see that Mongo stores all Dates as a 64bit integer from 1970, so maybe it's the mongo shell and how it returns data.

This was my original code in my BsonDateTypeAdapter, and I've added to it to handle the $numberLong format, but I'm still trying to understand why:

```
@Override
public Date read(final JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    if (in.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
        in.beginObject();
        String token = in.nextName();
        assert "$date".equals(token);
        String date = in.nextString();
        in.endObject();
        return DateFunctions.convertStringToDate(date);
    } else  {
        in.skipValue();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: See [Date](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/#date): *BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970). This results in a representable date range of about 290 million years into the past and future.* So, looks like there is an issue with your BsonDateAdapter

Comment: Do you run it on Windows? Look like Windows has (or had) some problems with dates before 1970, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12816

Comment: I agree, Mongo stores them as a 64 bit integer from 1970. But that doesn't answer why I have 2 scenarios in the same Mongo document with different formats. This is the first time I've ever seen the $numberLong format, all of the prior ones were plain string inside the $date. Also, this representation is something I see prior to my BsonDateAdapter being called. I can code for both formats but I'm trying to understand why I would need to.

Comment: It happens regardless of the environment it's running on. The Mongo server is not Windows, and the code is either a ubuntu server or my local windows development machine.